# How to solve Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift

I was searching for this issue here, and found out that this issue is not common one.

Everyone had different approaches to solve it. I'm using Firebase and Gifu framework. Actually for the last one - i copied all the files to my project, but that didn't helped either.

Here is my source code:

```
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import UIKit
import Gifu

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userImage: AnimatableImageView!

var displayedUserId = ""
var AcceptedOrRejected = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlArray = ["http://i.imgur.com/VAWlQ0S.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/JDzGqvE.gif", "http://67.media.tumblr.com/4cd2a04b60bb867bb4746d682aa60020/tumblr_mjs2dvWX6x1rvn6njo1_400.gif", "https://media.giphy.com/media/TlK63ELk5OPDzpb6Tao/giphy.gif", "http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y90/spicestas/GeriHalliwell-Calling-new1.gif", "http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnb9aozmM71qbxrlp.gif"]

    var counter = 1

    for url in urlArray {

        let nsUrl = NSURL(string: url)

        let girls = ProfileClass()

        girls.profilePhotoUrl = url
        girls.profileGender = "female"
        girls.profileName = "girlsname\(counter)"
        girls.profileSurname = "girlsurname\(counter)"
        girls.interest = "men"
        girls.uid = "\(randomStringWithLength(45))"

        counter++
        girls.SaveUser()


    }

    //----setting variables


    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100, self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 50, 300, 100))
    //label.text = "Drag me!"
    //label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    userImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    userImage.userInteractionEnabled = true



    //----getting access to database

    let thisUserRef = URL_BASE.childByAppendingPath("profile")


    thisUserRef.queryOrderedByChild("Interest").queryEqualToValue("men").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children{

            self.displayedUserId = (child.value["uid"] as? String)!

            let imageURL = child.value["photo"] as? String

            let imURL = NSURL(string: imageURL!)

            //print(imageURL)



            if self.AcceptedOrRejected != "" {

                let AcceptedArray = child.value[AcceptedOrRejected] as? Array

                AcceptedArray.append(displayedUserId)

            }







            if let picData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imURL!) {

                self.userImage.animateWithImageData(picData)
                //self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: picData)
            }


        }


    })






}

//-----Dragging function-----------

func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //set traslations
    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    let label = gesture.view



    //set center position
    label!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 - translation.y )

    let xfromCenter = (label?.center.x)! - self.view.bounds.width / 2

    let scale = min(100 / abs(xfromCenter),1)

    var rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(xfromCenter / 200)

    var strech = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scale, scale)

    label?.transform = strech



    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        if label?.center.x < 100 {

            self.AcceptedOrRejected = "Accepted"


        } else if label?.center.x > self.view.bounds.width / 100 {

            self.AcceptedOrRejected = "Rejected"

        }

        rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)
        strech = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, 1, 1)

        label?.transform = strech

        label?.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 , y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 )
    }

}


//---Function for generating randomn userid


func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

    for (var i=0; i < len; i += 1){
        let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
    }

    return randomString
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "LogOutSegue" {
        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    }


}
```

}

And I get this error

```
1.  While emitting SIL for 'viewDidLoad' at /Users/zkid18/Desktop/wrk/Bloom/Bloom/ViewController.swift:23:14
2.  While silgen closureexpr SIL function @_TFFC5Bloom14ViewController11viewDidLoadFT_T_U_FCSo15FIRDataSnapshotT_ for expression at [/Users/zkid18/Desktop/wrk/Bloom/Bloom/ViewController.swift:68:114 - line:107:9] RangeText="{
            snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children{

                self.displayedUserId = (child.value["uid"] as? String)!

                let imageURL = child.value["photo"] as? String

                let imURL = NSURL(string: imageURL!)

                //print(imageURL)



                if self.AcceptedOrRejected != "" {

                    let AcceptedArray = child.value[AcceptedOrRejected] as? Array

                    AcceptedArray.append(displayedUserId)

                }







                if let picData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imURL!) {

                    self.userImage.animateWithImageData(picData)
                    //self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: picData)
                }


            }


        }"
```

I don't really know what to do with that

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278233/swift-compiler-error-while-emitting-sil-for-tableview-at

Comment: That is a compiler crash. Trim that code down to the smallest possible thing that still causes the crash — compiler bugs can usually reproduced in less than a dozen lines — then submit it to Apple.

Comment: self.displayedUserId = (child.value["uid"] as? String)! makes me suspicious. I would not force unwrap like that. It's really easy to break that promise.

Comment: @Dare Actually, firstly I haven't wrapped it, but compiler made me do that

Comment: The compiler is warning you to conditionally unwrap it since you have an optional cast. I would try making that an if let or guard statement and see if it decides to compile. Same with all the other optionals you are force-unwrapping

Comment: I also have this problem, and have searched and found nothing. I very quick fix is to keep cleaning your project and building and running it and it will eventually build. Such a bug!

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted a conversion to Swift 3 to get a jump on fixing issues in my code. I have similar error but I just integrated Firebase into all of my project. I found that by removing the pod and framework from the app and commenting out all firebase code fixed this compile issue.

Comment: You mean to remove Firebase completely?

Comment: I removed/commented out the core stuff, admob was working fine. Still some bugs with Swift 3 and Firebase, but again I am not sure if the reference project is an Xcode 8/Swift 3 thing