# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 while emitting IR SIL function

Tags: swift, properties, closures, runtime, extension-methods

I want to add closure properties in the extension of `UITextView` so I  define a closure using typealias:

```
typealias TextViewHeightDidChangedClosure = (_ currentTextViewHeight:CGFloat)->Void

extension UITextView{

  func setTextViewHeightDidChanged(textViewHeightDidChanged:TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock){
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TextViewHeightDidChangedBlockKey, textViewHeightDidChanged, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
  }

  func textViewHeightDidChanged()->TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock?{
   let textChanged : ((CGFloat)->Void) = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TextViewHeightDidChangedBlockKey) as! TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock
    return textChanged
  }

}
```

But it tells me an error that says:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11.

Here is an image of the error

[image: my code]

Can anyone tell me why and give me an deep meaningful explanation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

You can also have this error if you declare a `Bool!` property in a class and you try to make a ternary condition with this property:

```
var isSomething: Bool!

func myFunc() {
    let value = isSomething ? "something" : "not"
}
```

Just add the ! on your property

```
var isSomething: Bool!

func myFunc() {
    let value = isSomething! ? "something" : "not"
}
```

Comment: Any insight into why the ternary causes a seg fault?

Comment: @Tyler if `isSomething` is nil, `isSomething!` will cause a seg fault due to force unwrapping an implicit optional

Answer (score 5):

Generally, crashing with SegFault 11 is a bug of compiler and you'd better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

And most such bugs can be worked around with fixing your code properly.

The most significantly bad thing in your code is that usual closures in Swift (`@convention(swift)` -- usually omitted) cannot be passed to `Any` which represents `id` of Objective-C. Use `@convention(block)` which is stated as *`id`-compatible* in the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097) ([this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID350)):

```
typealias TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock = @convention(block) (_ currentTextViewHeight:CGFloat)->Void
```

You may have tried this, but in this case, just putting `@convention(block)` does not solve the issue.

It seems another trick is needed to make your code work, explicitly cast to `AnyObject`:

```
extension UITextView{

    func setTextViewHeightDidChanged(textViewHeightDidChanged: @escaping TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock){
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TextViewHeightDidChangedBlockKey, textViewHeightDidChanged as! AnyObject, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
    }

    func textViewHeightDidChanged()->TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock?{
        let textChanged : ((CGFloat)->Void) = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TextViewHeightDidChangedBlockKey) as! TextViewHeightDidChangedBlock
        return textChanged
    }

}
```

So, this seems to be a flaw of [`id-as-Any`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md). `Any` which represents `id` should accept *`id`-compatible* closure.

I'm not sure Apple would fix this bug soon, but anyway, as far as I tested, my code above worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because I was declaring protocols for two extensions on a generic class and implementing them in the class declaration. I am using xCode 9 swift 4

Comment: I know this is old but it would be great to see a small example of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue in Xcode 9.3, I opened the given swift class as mentioned in error image(mine was differ), went to method(mention in error) there was code like below

```
class func makeViewCircular(view: AnyObject) {
    let viewCircle = view
    viewCircle.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width/2
    viewCircle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    viewCircle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
```

So, I edit the code to like below. Fixed the problem. The problem was with the AnyObject type. I typecast AnyObject to UIView.

```
class func makeViewCircular(view: AnyObject) {
    if let viewCircle = view as? UIView{
        viewCircle.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width/2
        viewCircle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        viewCircle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the swift class I am referring in Objective-C is missing `@objc`. I was using `@class` in my .h file and referring the swift class in header file. Might help someone as the error doesn't gives any clue about this.